# Ruby on Rails Nested Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have three Models: Deal, Zipcode, DealIncludeZipcode.

Now, the association looks like below:-

Deal Model:

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many  :deal_include_zipcodes, dependent: :destroy
  has_and_belongs_to_many  :zipcodes, dependent: :destroy
  
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :deal_include_zipcodes,:reject_if => :reject_include_zipcodes, allow_destroy: true
  
  private
    def reject_include_zipcodes(attributes)
      if attributes[:deal_id].blank? || attributes[:zipcode_id].blank?
        if attributes[:id].present?
          attributes.merge!({:_destroy => 1}) && false
        else
          true
        end
      end
    end
end

class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :deals
end


class DealIncludeZipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :deal
    belongs_to :zipcode
end
```

Now in view I have a checkbox,on unchecking it I can select multiple zipcode to select from DealIncludeZipcode. But when I save the data it is not saving.

I have used migration for joining Zipcode and Deal Model in which my exclude zipcode functionality is working correctly.

Please provide a solution. I have tried various method but didn't  succeed.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of `has_and_belongs_to_many` is that you don't have a model which joins the two parts.

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :zipcodes
end

class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :deals
end
```

Would join through a "headless" table called `deals_zipcodes`. If you want to have a join model you need to use `has_many :through` instead.

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_zipcodes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :zipcodes, through: :deal_zipcodes
end

class DealZipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :deal
  belongs_to :zipcode
end

class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :deal_zipcodes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :deals, through: :deal_zipcodes
end
```

Comment: I know that and I have used them for excluding zipcodes.

Comment: I have a functionality for including zipcodes. User can use including and excluding zipcodes by selecting a zipcodes that works on Jquery. Where and how to save data for Include zipcode as join table has data for Exclude Zipcode.

Comment: I still don't think you understand - your code is not using the `DealIncludeZipcode` model at all since the relations are defined wrong.

Comment: so, can you guide me what relation should be there, where I am doing it wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think Max's right. So your migration should be

```
create_table :deals do |t|
  t.string :name
  ...
end
create_table :zipcodes do |t|
  t.string :zipcode
  ...
end
create_table :deals_zipcodes do |t|
  t.belongs_to :deal, index: true
  t.belongs_to :zipcode, index: true
end
```

And your models should be

```
class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :zipcodes
end
class Zipcode < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :deals
end
```

You should probably take a look at the [ActiveRecord guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association), where you'll find more explanation.

Comment: I know that and I have these + I have one more extra table name DealIncludeZipcode.

Comment: Then why not just use DealIncludeZipcode as the joint table?

Comment: I mean the whole point of using has_and_belongs_to_many association is to create a joint table that doesn't hold on to any information other than the association itself. If you have additional information or logic that needs to go into the association, then just use has_many .. through .. would probably serve you better.

Comment: I have two functionalities if you read my question correctly.

Comment: If I use has many through then it shows Association Mismatch error.

Comment: I'm not sure how you implemented your has many through association. Maybe take a look at this post: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/accepts-nested-attributes-for-with-has-many-through